# Find an unknown

Tags: calculus

The gradient of the tangent at $(2,-3/2)$ on the curve $y=x^2+ax+b$ is equal to $3/2$. Find the values of $a$ and $b$.

I differentiated it and got:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+ax$

But how do I continue?

Comment: What do you mean by $\$?$

Comment: where is a and b in y??

Comment: Hold on. The original is like this:

Comment: The gradient of the tangent at (2,-3/2) on the curve y=x^2-3x is equal to 3/2. Find the values of a and b.

Comment: @DeepeshMeena Wait, what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, hang on a minute

Comment: where is $a$ and $b$ in the function

Comment: The gradient of the tangent at (2,-3/2) on the curve y=x^2+ax+b is equal to 3/2. Find the values of a and b.

Comment: Sorry for the entire mix up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivative should read $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x +a$.

You have been given the value for the gradient at $(2, -3/2)$. So put in that value for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and $x=2$. ($3/2 = 2 \times 2 + a $). This will give you $a$.

Then you can put $x, y, a$ into the original equation to find $b$.

Comment: Wait, wait, what does "plug in your values for the gradient at the 
x

coordinate" mean?

Comment: You have been given the value for the gradient at $(2, -3/2)$. So put in that value for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and $x=2$. This will give you $a$.

Comment: Oh thanks so much!

Comment: I'm still working on finding the answer, but of course!

Comment: @Kakeru Have you got there yet?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to put the numbers to the original equation in a way b would be found so I ended up doing another question. :( I suck at calculus

Comment: @Kakeru You now have the value of $a$, and the coordinates you are given for $x$ and $y$ mean you can put these numbers into $y = x^2 +ax +b$, and you will get $b = ...$

Comment: OMG OMG thank you so much!

Comment: Let's say y=2x^3-3x is parallel to y-3x+2=0. I need to find the equation of the tangent but I don't have the coordinates. What should I do?

Comment: If you have a different question you should attempt to solve it, and then post the question and your attempt in a separate question if you're still stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!